# Liquibase: tracking changelogs

Tags: maven, svn, liquibase, database-versioning

**The project**

We are ~50 developers plus DevOps staff and run ~30 Oracle 12c EE instances. We have introduced Liquibase in 2018.

We use the Liquibase Maven plugin version 3.8.8, changelogs are stored in numerous Maven projects, these are commited to subversion in the usual trunk/tag/branch structure.

**The Goal**

We want to ease provisioning of new database instances with release versions matching the respective environments. A typical use case is setting up a fresh database in the integration test environment.

One would start with an empty database schema and apply changelogs up to a certain version.
***Unfortunately, changelogs that were applied to a schema are often stored in different Maven projects. This makes them hard to locate.***

Liquibase does NOT store actual changeset contents (concrete DDL) in the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table. This would solve the problem.

In search of a solution, I first used maven to store the changelog's SVN revision into the `DATABASECHANGELOG` when liquibase:update was executed. 
Retrieving changelogs based on revision number was error prone.

I have spend a week now to find a robust solution, googled for hours and built several test cases (with adapted parent and and concrete poms, partly using the maven scm plugin and such) but without luck. Initially, I planned to use liquibase:tag to store file path + revision, but this works only if all changesets are in one single changelog file, which is not the case.

Of course, it's desirable to have all changelogs stored in ONE location,
but this is not always possible. For example, scripts that require DBA privileges must to be committed to extra maven projects.
I need a strong reference between each changeset and the corresponding changelog file, or the changelog must be stored directly in the `DATABASECHANGELOG`.

With our current setup, "Database versioning" with Liquibase is not possible. There is theoretical 
tracebility, but it is up to the users to somehow locate original changelogs in a huge mess of 100+ separate Maven projects.

**Question 1: Is it possible to store the actual changelog content for each changeset into the `DATABASECHANGELOG`?**

**Question 2: If not, how can one preserve a reference beetween a `DATABASECHANGELOG` entry and the originating changelog file?**

(Also, what happens, when a changelog file is deleted from subversion by accident? The `DATABASECHANGELOG` would just tell me the date and time of the change, some details and a file name - pretty useless, because the *actual* file would be gone and there would be no way to restore the actual DDL.  To prevent such a scenario, I would backup *all* changelog files. To do that, `DATABASECHANGELOG` meta data is insufficient, as Liquibase does not track SVN revisions and file paths.)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to combine various SVN repositories into new one using SVN Externals and then create new changelog file.
You can map URLs (SVN Tag/Branch/Revisions) to a folder without copying using SVN Externals. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html.

Hope it helps.